# How to find the number of vertices in a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose that a connected planar graph has 30 edges. If a planar representation of this graph divides the plane into 20 faces, how many vertices does this graph have?

I am not sure how to get started with this ? Please give me some idea.

Comment: Try to solve the same problem by drawing with a smaller amount for edges and faces. You should be able to notice a relation between the three sizes.

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to know about [*Euler's Characteristic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs), which applies also to connected, planar graphs.

Denote the number of vertices of a connected planar graph $G$ by $V$.

Likewise, denote the number of edges of the graph by $E$, and the number of faces of the graph by $F$. Then the following holds for every connected planar graph:

$$V - E + F = 2$$

You're given the number of edges $E$, and the number of faces $F$, so you simply need the formula above to calculate the number of vertices of your graph.